Potential leak of memory pointed to by <variable>
I wrote this function in Qt 6.8.0:
QActionGroup *group = new QActionGroup(ui->toolBar);
foreach (QAction *action, ui->toolBar->actions())
{
    action->setActionGroup(group);
    QWidget *w = ui->toolBar->widgetForAction(action);
    QToolButton *b = qobject_cast<QToolButton *>(w);
    if (b == nullptr) continue;
    b->setMinimumWidth(ui->toolBar->width());
}

where ui->toolbar is the QToolBar on my QMainWindow and it contains some checkable actions, for example:

This code handles all the actions as a group, so they can be checked one at time.
It works.
But clang complains about a potential memory leak:

Potential leak of memory pointed to by 'group' [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks]

I tried to delete the pointer adding at the end of the function:
delete group;

but if I delete this pointer my code does not work anymore: I can check multiple actions.
What is the correct way to avoid a memory leak while keeping my code working?

clang doesn't understand that the ui->toolBar object will manage the lifetime of its new child object group. There is no leak as far as I can tell

Do you have other reports from sanitizer? Potential leak is most often reported, when actually owner of this pointer is leaking. For example your MainWindow is not properly handled and this QActionGroup is one of the childs of it.

@MarekR, I don't have any other report

As long as QObjects are created with a parent, they don't create any leak, as Qt automatically manages their lifetime. The compiler may just not be aware of that. See Object Trees & Ownership.
